# QWebKit с Adobe Flash Player

Tags: qt, webkit, adobe

Что нужно сделать, чтобы получилось просмотреть видео?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого необходимо активировать плагины:

```
QWebSettings* settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Если просмотр Flash все равно не доступен, то указать директорию, где располагается плагин Adobe. Например, на Windows так:

```
qputenv("QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH","C:\Windows\SysWow64\Macromed\Flash");
```

Comment: Спасибо, ответ принимается, награду по конкурсу пока не смогу присудить -- сайт только через сутки позволит